# DataGridView with DataGridViewComboBoxColumns fill Selection after sorting

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

I have a `DataGridView` which is bound to a SQL result. Afterwards I add three `DataGridViewComboBoxColumns` manually, which are populated by corresponding SQL results.

When choosing an entry from each of the `DataGridViewComboBoxCells`, the `ValueMember` is saved to the database.

As soon as the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumns` are added, a preselect function is called, which reads the selected values from the database, to always see the last state.

Until now everything is working as expected.
The problem is, as soon as I sort the `DataGridView` by clicking on any of the column heads, the `DataGridViewComboBoxCells` are not preselected any more.

So, I thought, by adding a `.Sorted` event handler which calls my preselect function would solve this problem. But the selection is not done any more.

```
function PreselectComboBoxes(int IdJob) {
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewHotels.Rows)
            {
               ... // iteration through all rows and set value read from database by reading ID number from first column
            }
}
```

As the ID for the database can be read directly from the row, I do not see, why it does not work this way.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: It is difficult to visualize what you are describing as far as the combo box columns are concerned. It is unclear if the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumns` are part of the grids `DataSource` or are the columns completely “detached” from the grids `DataSource` … ? … If the combo box columns are “detached” from the data source, then, if you sort the grid, then those “detached” combo box cells will all get reset back to the initial state. However, this is a guess as you did not supply this information.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought it was clear, that the `DataGridView` has it's `DataSource`and the `DataGridViewComboBoxColums`are added afterwards and do have their own `DataSource`. 
I also understand, that the `ComboBoxCells` do get reset to initial state after sorting.
And in the moment of writing this, I think I now understand what the problem is.
As the `ComboBoxes`are reset to initial state, they do not have any entries any more. So before doing the selection again in the `event handler`, they have to be repoulated again.
I will give it a try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: _”So before doing the selection again in the event handler, they have to be repoulated again.”_ … ? … I would try and avoid doing something like that. Without question, maintaining the combo boxes that are “detached” from the grids data source is not going to be trivial. And I am confident you may have to call the code many times when in reality the data has not changed. If you have the combo data in the DB… then either get the combo data in the initial query for the grid data source or “combine” the data as one data source. This will eliminate your current problem and will make things easier.